# C# String to pointer in unmanaged class library

Tags: c#, pointers, dllexport, stdcall

An existing application is going to import my class library. I am trying to do this in C# since I have a lot more experience in C# than C++. The existing application uses __stdcall which is originally not possible with C# since the code is managed. I use a library called RGiesecke.DllExport to do unmanaged exports.

```
[DllExport("LibraryOpen", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static int LibraryOpen(int* session, char* description)
{
    //I need to fill description here.
}
```

I have an example header of the function in C/C++

```
typedef int (__stdcall *LibraryOpen)(int *session, WCHAR *description);
```

The purpose of this function is, that I fill the description pointer with a short description of my library.

The problem is that I am not sure if char* is a good use here, and I don't know how to fill this pointer with a string.

I hope someone can help me with this, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: desc = new char[str.Length];
for (int i=0; i < str.Length; i++)
str[i] = desc[i]

Comment: This seems a bit vague but look up Marshal.PtrToStructure this might help

Comment: I think StringBuilder will marshal across.